# Extract version from string with Regular Expression and lookahead

Tags: regex, powershell

I have the following string as an example, it is expected that version numbers will change in the future and it's possible that order changes or other types are added)

```
Flash Player 12.0.0.38 (Internet Explorer); 12.0.0.43 (Plugin-based browsers)
```

I want to parse this with RegEx in the following manner:

- Find (Internet Explorer) and capture the version (12.0.0.38) preceeding it
- Find (Plugin-based browsers) and capture the version preceeding it

My tries so far:

```
$text = "Flash Player 12.0.0.38 (Internet Explorer); 12.0.0.43 (Plugin-based browsers)"
[RegEx]::Match($text, ".*(?=\(Internet\040Explorer\))").Value
```

That returns Flash Player 12.0.0.38

So I think I need to filter for "one or more words" and not capture those, then capture "one or more digits or ." when followed by (Internet Explorer) I tried:

```
[RegEx]::Match($text, "(?:\w+)[\d\.]+(?=\(Internet\040Explorer\))").Value
```

But that does not match, is the order incorrect? So I am looking for the correct regex with a small explanation.

Comment: Why not `'([\d.])+(?= \(Internet\040Explorer\))'`?

Comment: @devnull probably because I do not understand regex well enough :D

Perhaps you can add this as an answer and explain why it's not `([\d\.]+)` instead of `([\d\.])+`

Comment: The only problems with your expression `(?:\w+)[\d\.]+(?=\(Internet\040Explorer\))` is that the `(?:\w+)` isn't needed and the `[\d\.]+` part doesn't account for the space after the version number.

Comment: Remko - I have need to detect the exact flash version you have there: 12.0.0.38 -- curious HOW you were able to derive that. My usage of DetectFlashVer is not giving me the proper detection.. how are you detecting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$text = "Flash Player 12.0.0.38 (Internet Explorer); 12.0.0.43 (Plugin-based browsers)"
$Regex = '[\d\.]+';
$Matches = [Regex]::Matches($text, $Regex);

$Matches[0].Value;
$Matches[1].Value;
```

Result looks like:

```
12.0.0.38
12.0.0.43
```

**EDIT**: I have modified the regex to match, regardless of the order.

```
Clear-Host;

$matches = $null;
$Regex = '(?<=Flash Player\s)(?<FlashIE>[\d\.]+)(?:.*?)(?<FlashPlugin>[\d\.]+)(?=\s\(Plu)|(?<FlashPlugin>[\d\.]+)(?=\s\(Plu)(?:.*?)(?<=Flash Player\s)(?<FlashIE>[\d\.]+)';

# 1. Example string
$text = "Flash Player 12.0.0.38 (Internet Explorer); 12.0.0.43 (Plugin-based browsers)"
$MatchList = [Regex]::Matches($text, $Regex);
$MatchList[0].Groups['FlashIE'].Value;
$MatchList[0].Groups['FlashPlugin'].Value;

# 2. Reversed example string
$text = "; 12.0.0.43 (Plugin-based browsers);Flash Player 12.0.0.38 (Internet Explorer)"
$MatchList = [Regex]::Matches($text, $Regex);
$MatchList[0].Groups['FlashIE'].Value;
$MatchList[0].Groups['FlashPlugin'].Value;

# NOTE: Both of these yield the exact, same output, because we are using named groups.
```

Result:

```
12.0.0.38
12.0.0.43
12.0.0.38
12.0.0.43
```

Comment: But I am never sure of the order, this string might change in the future (will edit the question to make this more clear)

Comment: @Remko: I updated my answer, so it now matches when the order of elements is reversed.

Answer (score 1):

A little improvement with named groups:

```
if ($text -cmatch '(?<plugin>(?:\d\.?)+) (?=\(Plugin-based browsers\))|(?<internet>(?:\d\.?)+) (?=\(Internet Explorer\))') {
    $PluginBrowsers = $matches['plugin']
    $InternetExplorer = $matches['internet']
}
```

You could try this (no tested):

Using two regular expressions:

```
if ($subject -cmatch '((?:\d\.?)+) (?=\(Internet Explorer\))') {
   $result = $matches[1]
} else {
   $result = ''
}

if ($subject -cmatch '((?:\d\.?)+) (?=\(Plugin-based browsers\))') {
   $result = $matches[1]
} else {
   $result = ''
}
```

Or just one:

```
if ($subject -cmatch '((?:\d\.?)+) ((?=\(Plugin-based browsers\))|(?=\(Internet Explorer\)))') {
   $result = $matches[1]
} else {
   $result = ''
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason 
`(?:\w+)[\d\.]+(?=\(Internet\040Explorer\))` doesn't match is because the `[\d\.]+(?=\(Internet\040Explorer\))` part isn't expecting a space between the version number and `(Internet Explorer)`

This expression will capture both of the required values no matter the order:

```
(?=^.*?([\d\.]+)(?=(?> *)(?:\(Internet\040Explorer\))))(?=^.*?([\d\.]+)(?=(?> *)(?:\(Plugin-based browsers\))))
```

In powershell:

```
$text = "Flash Player 12.0.0.38 (Internet Explorer); 12.0.0.43 (Plugin-based browsers)"
$regex = "(?=^.*?([\d\.]+)(?=(?> *)(?:\(Internet\040Explorer\))))(?=^.*?([\d\.]+)(?=(?> *)(?:\(Plugin-based browsers\))))"
$matches  = [RegEx]::Match($text, $regex)
echo $Matches.Groups[1].value  #Outputs 12.0.0.38
echo $Matches.Groups[2].value  #Outputs 12.0.0.43
```

Example order:

```
Flash Player 12.0.0.38 (Internet Explorer); 12.0.0.43 (Plugin-based browsers)
[Match number 1]
Matched: '' at character 1
[Capture Group 1] '12.0.0.38' found at character 14
[Capture Group 2] '12.0.0.43' found at character 45
```

Reverse example order:

```
12.0.0.43 (Plugin-based browsers); Flash Player 12.0.0.38 (Internet Explorer)
[Match number 1]
Matched: '' at character 1
[Capture Group 1] '12.0.0.38' found at character 49
[Capture Group 2] '12.0.0.43' found at character 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're not sure what order they might be in:

```
$text = "Flash Player 12.0.0.38 (Internet Explorer); 12.0.0.43 (Plugin-based browsers)"

$IE_Version = $text -replace '.+\s([0-9.]+)\s\(Internet Explorer\).*','$1'
$Plugin_Version = $text -replace '.+\s([0-9.]+)\s\(Plugin-based browsers\).*','$1'

$IE_Version
$Plugin_Version

12.0.0.38
12.0.0.43
```

Briefly, the regex logic is:

Search the string until you find a space followed by a wad of digits and dots, followed by another space and then the literal string (Internet Explorer). Capture the wad of digits and dots, and replace the entire string with just that capture.  Repeat with the literal string (Plugin-based browsers) .

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
([0-9.]*)(?: (\(Internet Explorer\)|\(Plugin-based browsers\)))
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/m3nSbSQI2HB2FLTI)

Test it [here](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=7e7b7f4c-3ec6-43ca-9f45-2b661ed8f4c9).

Comment: That returns `12.0.0.38 (Internet Explorer)` and `12.0.0.43 (Plugin-based browsers)` (but I like the readability of it). To make it return only version `(?:` must be changed to `(?=`